# CodeIgniter: controller outputting JS - how to prevent response headers from returning cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a CI controller that outputs some JS variables (mainly language variables). I set the MIME type using `header` function, etc. So, it's really JS when it's outputted.

Looking at the header responses, I see session data being returned. As an optimization, I would like to prevent that from being returned (saved a few bytes). Is there a way for me to do this?

For my regular JS, CSS, etc. files, I put them on a sub-domain that does not set session/cookies. But since JS this is coming from my application's controller, it has session data.

Comment: Please make your comment an answer so I can accept this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as headers (which cookies are) have not been sent already, the [`header_remove`](http://php.net/header_remove) function can be used to remove them before they are send to the browser.

It might be that this makes especially sense as codeigniter sends all session data as a round-trip.

To inspect outgoing headers, PHP's [`headers_list`](http://php.net/headers_list) function is handy.